# How to convert string type timestamp value to timestamp type in pyspark? I am getting null

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I am trying to convert this type of string type timestamp ("2023-03-02T07:32:00+00:00") to timestamp and I am getting null values, I tried various stackoverflow suggestions but no luck.

Method 1 (Here I tried changing 'Z' at the end of timestamp format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'x'") with 'Z' and 'x'):

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import to_timestamp, col, from_utc_timestamp, unix_timestamp
display(
    df.withColumn("timestamp_utc", from_utc_timestamp(col("timestamp"), "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'x'"))
    .withColumn("timestamp_test", col("timestamp_utc").cast("timestamp"))
```

Method 2 (Here I tried changing 'Z' at the end of timestamp format ("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'") with 'X' and 'x'):

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import to_timestamp, col
display(df.withColumn("new_ts_ms", to_timestamp(col("timestamp"), "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'")))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You was close, you need to set the right format, in your case it's "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX", here's the code:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
df = spark.createDataFrame([["2023-03-02T07:32:00+00:00"]], ['timestamp'])
df = df.withColumn("timestamp_utc", to_timestamp("timestamp", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX"))
df.show(truncate=False)
df.printSchema()

+-------------------------+-------------------+
|timestamp                |timestamp_utc      |
+-------------------------+-------------------+
|2023-03-02T07:32:00+00:00|2023-03-02 08:32:00|
+-------------------------+-------------------+

root
 |-- timestamp: string (nullable = true)
 |-- timestamp_utc: timestamp (nullable = true)
```

Comment: Additionally, in spark the default timezone is the timezone of your computer. It means, if you do not define a timezone in the spark settings (spark.conf.set("spark.sql.session.timeZone", "UTC")), your results might differ from what you would have expected. This is the reason why you have 08:32:00 in the timestamp_utc column instead of 07:32:00

Comment: Thank you both for your inputs, I tried df = df.withColumn("timestamp_utc", to_timestamp("timestamp", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX")) and still getting null values in the new column timestamo_utc.

Comment: @rakk You should add a reproducible example to your post.

Comment: @AbdennacerLachiheb, Thanks for your quick responses. I just got a solution, there is a double quote which should be removed and then we have to use to_timestamp with date format.
 from pyspark.sql.functions import to_timestamp, regexp_replace, col

df = (df.withColumn("timestamp", regexp_replace("timestamp", '"', ''))
.withColumn("timestamp_utc", to_timestamp("timestamp", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX")).select("timestamp", "timestamp_utc")
)

Comment: @AbdennacerLachiheb Definitely it helped,upvoted, Thanks!!